# Flickering css animations on iPad

Tags: css

On https://infopoint.promosi.de/pharmatechnik/ixos-4-circle/ I have some css3-animations opening content-boxes clicking on the segments of the circle.
The animations are build like that:

```
.toggle-box.slide-in-elliptic-right-fwd {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: slide-in-elliptic-right-fwd 0.7s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both;
animation: slide-in-elliptic-right-fwd 0.7s cubic-bezier(.25, .46, .45, .94) both;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

}

```
@keyframes slide-in-elliptic-right-fwd {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(500px) rotateY(-30deg) scale(0);
    transform: translateX(500px) rotateY(-30deg) scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 200%;
    transform-origin: 0 200%;
    opacity: 0
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
    transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: -850px 50%;
    transform-origin: -850px 50%;
    opacity: 1
}
}
```

As you can see I already tried to use -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; but the flickering is still present.

Any hints how to get rid of them?

Edit: in the meantime I added the following rules:

```
.toggle-box div {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
.toggle-box {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
body {-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);}
```

This makes things better, but still not perfect. The boxes on the right side still are flickering a bit.

I have problems now with my footer-navigation, it has position:fixed and at least on iPad at initial load it is there, but scrolling up and down again makes it disappear. And, further on, on page load I have a loading-screen and it shows for a while the headlines of the resulting page. Like that it's not a solution and I'm stucked now.

I tried it as well with

```
-webkit-tranform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

But it doesn't change the bugs I described recently.

The code I have to use for the css-animations I got from another website. They have the same css for the circle-animations (without this workarounds I tried) and there is no flickering. But I can't get the difference and don't have any idea anymore.The original circle can be found under https://www.pharmatechnik.de/digitale-apotheke/

Answer (score 0):

Everything back :) The solution was found in the footer and not in the animated boxes. Something went wrong in css-declaration of the fixed footer and now everything works fine.
Cheers, Joe